# How to test a private function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, junit, junit5

I have two objects remote model and domain model

**Remote model**

```kotlin
data class InstanceRemoteModel (
    val id: String,
    val containers: List<Container>,
    val operations: List<Operation>
)

data class ContainerRemoteModel (
    val id: String,
    val capacity: Long
)

data class OperationRemoteModel (
    val id: String,
    val weight: Long,
    val containerId: String
)
```

**Domain Model**

```kotlin
data class Instance (
    val id: String,
    val containers: Map<String, Container>,
    val operations: Map<String, Operation>
)

data class Container (
    val id: String,
    val capacity: Long
    val total_weight: Long
)

data class Operation (
    val id: String,
    val weight: Long,
    val container: Container
)
```

And then I have a **mapper** that map objects from remote model to domain model. Here I will concentrate on mapping the containers. Note that a `Container` object in the domain model have different properties than `ContainerRemoteModel`. The same thing is done with the operations.

```kotlin
object Mapper {
  fun toDomainModel(remoteInstance: InstanceRemoteModel): Instance {
    val containers : Map<String, Container> = mapContainers(remoteInstance)
    val operations : Map<String, Operation> = mapOperations(remoteInstance)
    return Instance(remoteInstance.id,containers,operations)
  }



  private fun  mapContainers(remoteInstance: InstanceRemoteModel) : Map<String, Container> {
    //do some computations
    val containers : List<Container> = remoteInstance.containers.map { cont -> Container(...)}
    return containers.associateBy({ it.id }, { it }
  }

  private fun mapOperations(remoteInstance: InstanceRemoteModel): Map<String, Operation> {
    ...
  }
}
```

**My question is : How to properly test the mapper? Note that `mapOperations` and `mapContainers` are private functions.**

Comment: I added a comment below the answer. Please clarify where you are stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in unit testing, you need to test **only the public methods!**
if a private function isn't covered by testing the class public functions then that function is an island and no one using it and the compiler will alert about it.

been says that if you still want to test this function

you can use reflection to access any field you want

by adding this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.20</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

then you can test it

```
class MapperTest : TestCase(){

    @Test
    fun `test private method`(){
        val input = InstanceRemoteModel("test", emptyList(), emptyList())
        val returnValue = Mapper.invokePrivateFunction("mapContainers",input) as Map<String, Container>
        assert(returnValue.isEmpty())
    }

    inline fun <reified T> T.invokePrivateFunction(name: String, vararg args: Any?): Any? =
        T::class
            .declaredMemberFunctions
            .firstOrNull { it.name == name }
            ?.apply { isAccessible = true }
            ?.call(this, *args)
}
```

Comment: I am ok with the fact that I should not test private function. However the function `fun toDomainModel` is NOT private. So I am asking how to test it ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking Giant8. You would test it the same as any function, by calling it with a variety of different inputs and checking that it behaves as wanted. Maybe if you write an example of you want to test it in the question?